nhdplusTools: get_split_catchment not delineating entire watershed catchment basin above pour point
I am trying to delineate a watershed catchment basin from a pour point using the function get_split_catchment() from the package nhdplusTools. The function correctly delineates the COMID associated with the pour point however, it seems to stop running when it runs into the next upstream COMID. The ideal output would be a delineated basin for the entire upstream area of the provided pour point.
library(tidyverse)
library(nhdplusTools)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# 1. Define the starting point (pour point) ----
start_point <- st_sfc(st_point(c(-78.3361152, 38.9767759)), crs = 4269)

# Snap point to the nearest NHDPlus flowline
trace <- get_raindrop_trace(start_point)

snap_point <- st_sfc(st_point(trace$intersection_point[[1]]),
                         crs = 4326)

# 2. Retrieve NHDPlus COMID for the snapped point ----
start_comid <- discover_nhdplus_id(snap_point)

# 3. Navigate and extract upstream tributary flowlines ----
flowline <- navigate_nldi(list(featureSource = "comid", 
                               featureID = start_comid), 
                          mode = "upstreamTributaries", 
                          distance_km = 1000)

# 4. Download and subset NHDPlus data for the flowlines ----
subset_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".gpkg")
subset <- subset_nhdplus(comids = as.integer(flowline$UT$nhdplus_comid),
                         output_file = subset_file,
                         nhdplus_data = "download", 
                         flowline_only = FALSE,
                         return_data = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
#> All intersections performed in latitude/longitude.
#> Reading NHDFlowline_Network
#> Writing NHDFlowline_Network
#> Reading CatchmentSP
#> Writing CatchmentSP
flowline <- subset$NHDFlowline_Network

# Define the NLDI feature list for the starting COMID ----
nldi_nwis <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = start_comid)

# 5. Delineate the basin for the snap point ----
basin <- get_split_catchment(snap_point, upstream = TRUE)
basin <- basin[2,3]

# 6. Visualize watershed ----
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = flowline, color = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = basin, fill = NA, color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = start_point, color = "green", size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "green") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black'))

In the figure below, the delineated basin is the red area, the pour point is the green dot and the flowlines are the blue lines.


sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
#> Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
#> 
#> time zone: America/New_York
#> tzcode source: internal
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] sf_1.0-16          nhdplusTools_1.2.1 lubridate_1.9.3    forcats_1.0.0     
#>  [5] stringr_1.5.1      dplyr_1.1.4        purrr_1.0.2        readr_2.1.5       
#>  [9] tidyr_1.3.1        tibble_3.2.1       ggplot2_3.5.1      tidyverse_2.0.0   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] gtable_0.3.5         xfun_0.45            tzdb_0.4.0          
#>  [4] vctrs_0.6.5          tools_4.4.1          generics_0.1.3      
#>  [7] curl_5.2.1           parallel_4.4.1       proxy_0.4-27        
#> [10] fansi_1.0.6          pkgconfig_2.0.3      KernSmooth_2.23-24  
#> [13] data.table_1.15.4    assertthat_0.2.1     lifecycle_1.0.4     
#> [16] farver_2.1.2         compiler_4.4.1       munsell_0.5.1       
#> [19] fst_0.9.8            htmltools_0.5.8.1    class_7.3-22        
#> [22] yaml_2.3.9           pillar_1.9.0         classInt_0.4-10     
#> [25] hydroloom_1.0.2      cachem_1.1.0         wk_0.9.2            
#> [28] zip_2.3.1            tidyselect_1.2.1     digest_0.6.36       
#> [31] stringi_1.8.4        arrow_16.1.0         fastmap_1.2.0       
#> [34] grid_4.4.1           colorspace_2.1-0     cli_3.6.3           
#> [37] magrittr_2.0.3       utf8_1.2.4           e1071_1.7-14        
#> [40] withr_3.0.0          scales_1.3.0         bit64_4.0.5         
#> [43] timechange_0.3.0     rmarkdown_2.27       httr_1.4.7          
#> [46] dataRetrieval_2.7.15 bit_4.0.5            RANN_2.6.1          
#> [49] hms_1.1.3            fstcore_0.9.18       memoise_2.0.1       
#> [52] pbapply_1.7-2        evaluate_0.24.0      knitr_1.48          
#> [55] s2_1.1.7             rlang_1.1.4          Rcpp_1.0.12         
#> [58] glue_1.7.0           DBI_1.2.3            xml2_1.3.6          
#> [61] reprex_2.1.1         rstudioapi_0.16.0    jsonlite_1.8.8      
#> [64] R6_2.5.1             fs_1.6.4             units_0.8-5

Created on 2024-07-31 with reprex v2.1.1

Turns out this is a rare yet known issue and can be resolved by slightly adjusting the lat/long pour point.
library(tidyverse)
library(nhdplusTools)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# 1. Define the starting point (pour point) ----
start_point <- st_sfc(st_point(c(-78.336, 38.976)), crs = 4326)

# Snap point to the nearest NHDPlus flowline
trace <- get_raindrop_trace(start_point)

# Use the intersection point as the pour point
snap_point <- st_sfc(st_point(trace$intersection_point[[1]]),
                         crs = 4326)

# 2. Retrieve NHDPlus COMID for the snapped point ----
start_comid <- discover_nhdplus_id(snap_point)

# 3. Navigate and extract upstream tributary flowlines ----
flowline <- navigate_nldi(list(featureSource = "comid", 
                               featureID = start_comid), 
                          mode = "upstreamTributaries", 
                          distance_km = 1000)

# 4. Download and subset NHDPlus data for the flowlines ----
subset_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".gpkg")
subset <- subset_nhdplus(comids = as.integer(flowline$UT$nhdplus_comid),
                         output_file = subset_file,
                         nhdplus_data = "download", 
                         flowline_only = FALSE,
                         return_data = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
#> All intersections performed in latitude/longitude.
#> Reading NHDFlowline_Network
#> Writing NHDFlowline_Network
#> Reading CatchmentSP
#> Writing CatchmentSP
flowline <- subset$NHDFlowline_Network

# Define the NLDI feature list for the starting COMID ----
nldi_nwis <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = start_comid)

# 5. Delineate the basin for the snap point ----
basin <- get_split_catchment(snap_point, upstream = TRUE)
basin <- basin[2,3]

# 6. Visualize watershed ----
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = flowline, color = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = basin, fill = NA, color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = start_point, color = "green", size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "green") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black'))


Created on 2024-07-31 with reprex v2.1.1
